# Express resolving route before API call completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Ok, full disclosure I am a hobby coder so I understand there to be gaps in my knowledge. However I've tried all sorts of solutions for this and have been unable to get a working answer.

**DESIRED RESULT**

I make a call to my Express server, it fetches data from an external API and renders once the data has been retrieved.

**PROBLEM**

I cannot seem to make Express wait no matter how I lay out the `async/await` pattern. Currently my code is as follows:

```
Express.js

app.get('/getInventory', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let inventory = await api.getInventory(req.query.id)
    console.log(inventory)
    res.json(inventory)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

My `api.js` is currently as such:

```
exports.getInventory = async function(id){
    let data = await manager.getInventoryContents(id, 570, 2, true, (err, inventory) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            Promise.reject(err)
        } 
        else {
            console.log('Success')
            Promise.resolve(inventory)
        }
    })
    return data
}
```

In case you're wondering I have the `console.log()` actions just to try and see when something is happening.

**WHAT I AM GETTING SO FAR**

With just about every variation I am getting the `Express.js` inventory as `undefined` (similarly no data being sent to the client), however I AM receiving a `Success` message (or even the inventory itself) from `api.js`.

I am guessing the right syntax is obvious once I complete it but I cannot seem to get it to function properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
exports.getInventory = async function(id){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      manager.getInventoryContents(id, 570, 2, true, (err, inventory) => {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
         } 
         else {
            console.log('Success');
            resolve(inventory);
         }
      }
   }
}
```